# Filling stations and petrol stations in Nigeria, is there any difference?

Tags: nigeria, gas-stations

While browsing [north Nigeria's map](https://www.google.pl/maps/@13.2968187,5.4216775,16.75z?hl=en) I have noticed that "places where you can fuel your car" (?) are named both "Filling Station" and "Petrol Station":

[image]

Is there any difference between these? Or is this purely a naming convention?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is the same thing.

Apparently, according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filling_station), the most common name in the world is a *filling station*:

> **A filling station** that sells only electric energy is also known as a charging station, while a typical filling station can also be known as a fueling or gas station (United States and Canada), gasbar (Canada), gasoline stand or SS[Note 1] (Japan), petrol pump or petrol bunk (India, Pakistan and Bangladesh), garage, **petrol station** (Australia, Hong Kong, New Zealand, Singapore, South Africa, United Kingdom and Ireland), service station (Australia, France, Italy, Japan, New Zealand and United Kingdom and Ireland), servo (Australia), or fuel station (Northern Europe and Israel).

This is probably a naming preference/incosistency on the map.

Comment: As usual Wikipedia is slightly off: a "service station" offers vehicle repair services, and usually also offers petrol. This is not true of "servo" in Australia today though, which can now refer to any petrol station.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I would suggest that "service station" for New Zealand maybe in the past offered vehicle repair services, but now the majority of service stations just sell fuel and food.  I don't know if this is reflected elsewhere in the "service station" world.